# exe created from mBlock source code gives not a valid win32 application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, win32exception

I am trying to compile the mBlock source code from github (https://github.com/Makeblock-official/mBlock/tree/V3.4.5)

I followed all the steps that are present in the tutorial from mBlock in 'HOW TO COMPILE MBLOCK'.

My problem is that mblock runs in the 'Debug Mode' in Flash Builder 4.7 (Trial version). But when I export the release build, with 'native installer' or 'captive runtime' option, then running the executable gives error that '[application name] is not a valid win32 application'

I have tried that on 3 different laptops. On all three laptops (each has x64 bit architecture), the mblock code compiles and runs perfectly in the Debug mode but when export the build, it gives 'win32 application' error.

Thank you

Comment: Have you successfully compiled (to exe) other working AIR apps recently? Just confirm that you don't get same error if you make a simple "hello world" textfield and then export with _"native installer (exe)"_ selected. After installing (put icon on desktop, etc), if you still got error then go the install folder and right-click the exe to choose _"properties"_ then either choose "Win XP compatibility" or even try "Run as Admin" (set this for all users)...

Comment: Yes I have tried that. I made a blank project, then compile this blank application into a native installer (which works after installation) and captive run-time (which just gives an application exe and an swf file of main application file). By the way I am using windows 7 x64 bit. The source code uses three ANEs files and I have also added them to packaging option. Though I have not tried to add a random ANE file when I was making an executable of a blank project.

Comment: Well it's strange that it runs fine for debugging but not with final output. My last _"not a valid win32 application"_ issue was fixed by setting properties to run in  "Windows XP compatibility mode" but as you say it did not help you... Later I will download the files and see whats up, I might learn something new...

Comment: Well, my issue is solved. Turned out I was using AirSDK21 but the I had Air runtime 24 installed. When I installed the AirSDK24, the installer package installed correctly and is working now. Thank you though

Comment: Post your solution as Answer for others. Glad it's sorted. It worked for me too when testing, so without ability to **exactly** reproduce your error, I could not advise you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my issue is solved. Turned out I was using AirSDK21 but the I had Air runtime 24 installed. When I installed the AirSDK24, the installer package installed correctly and is working now. Thank you though